# SkypeKit to make PC to phone calls

Tags: c++, skype

Can someone tell me if its possible to use the skypekit api to write a c++ win32 console application to make pc to phone calls only(nothing else) on windows 7 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on some stuff with the SkypeKit API and it should definitely be possible. There's an example application included that has the basic functionality for doing it.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I bought the account and it worked with the application documentation